# Get selected value from select_tag and pass it as a parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a separate **select_tag** and a **link_to** and I'm sending some parameters via the **link_to**. I want to get the *selected value* and send it as one of the parameters. I tried to add `selected: params[:whatever]` to the *select_tag*, that didn't work. I tried doing it via js, I can get the selected value but I'm not sure how to set to that specific parameter.

As requested:

```
<%= select_tag :shipping_opt, options_for_select(delivery_opt(@select_store)), :include_blank => true %>


<%= link_to 'Use this address', checkouts_step_two_path(:data => Checkout::CRYPT.encrypt_and_sign(s.id), :store => Checkout::CRYPT.encrypt_and_sign(@select_store.id), :order_info => ?? )  %>
```

the order_info should be the selected shipping opt.

Comment: Can you please add your full form/link_to to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you retrieve values from the `select_tag` with a format similar to this:

`value = $('#selectList').val();`

I'd assume that you just set this to a variable and put it into the params hash in the `link_to`

`<%= link_to 'Use this address', checkouts_step_two_path(:data => Checkout::CRYPT.encrypt_and_sign(s.id), :store => Checkout::CRYPT.encrypt_and_sign(@select_store.id), **:order_info => value** )  %>`

Comment: I got: undefined local variable or method `value' :c

Comment: Do you have jquery installed? Also did you replace the name #selectList with your select_tag name?

Comment: yes, I have jquery. I also replaced it. what I have now is $('#shipping_opt').val(). Will using 'escape_javascript' or 'javascript_tag' somehow help?

Comment: oh haha, yeah you probably have to use a javascript tag I believe

Comment: oh I'm sorry. I didn't know what 'javascript_tag' was lolz. I'm so tired. yeah yeah I just add <script></script> the normal way before the body. What i meant is there a function or smth related to js I don't know about.

Comment: I believe it should work like this: `javascript_tag "alert('All is good')"`

Comment: no :c i ended up changing it to a form. and using a hidden field. appreciate your effort!